# Unexpected end of file in a shell script, cant find the mistake

Tags: linux, shell, upload, raspberry-pi, eof

HEy there i wrote this little shell script for my pi to upload a picture, but everytime i run the script i get "Unexpected end of file" I does not even show me the first echo.

Thanks for your help :)

```
raspistill -o snapshot2.jpg
HOST=XXXXX  #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
USER= XXXX            #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
PASS=XXXXX        #This is the password for the FTP user.
NOW=$(date +"%c")

echo test

if [ -f work ];
then
    echo >> ftp.log "$NOW Script failure"
    echo ein prozess arbeitet noch

else
    echo beginne upload
    touch work
        ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
    user $USER $PASS
    cd /bilder2/
    put snapshot2.jpg   
    bye

    echo >> ftp.log "$NOW Upload Success"
    rm work
    echo erfolgreicher upload 
fi

EOF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fi` should be placed *after* `EOF`, my guess would be that your script should look like:

```
raspistill -o snapshot2.jpg
HOST=XXXXX  #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
USER= XXXX            #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
PASS=XXXXX        #This is the password for the FTP user.
NOW=$(date +"%c")

echo test

if [ -f work ];
then
    echo >> ftp.log "$NOW Script failure"
    echo ein prozess arbeitet noch

else
    echo beginne upload
    touch work
    ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASS
cd /bilder2/
put snapshot2.jpg   
bye
EOF
    echo >> ftp.log "$NOW Upload Success"
    rm work
    echo erfolgreicher upload 
fi
```